# Store toggle input to SQLite database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

now i'm working with Intel XDK using Ionic framework.

i've succesfully store data to database using SQLite database, and now i want to store Toggle input button to database but i don't know how to do that.

Here is my code to input to SQLite :

```
var insertKasir = "INSERT INTO Kasir (namamenu) VALUES (?)";
var selectKasir = "SELECT * FROM Kasir";
function insertRecord(){
var namamenutemp = $('input:text[id=namamenu]').val();
db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(insertKasir, [namamenutemp]); });
}
function showRecords() {

$("#results").html('')
db.transaction(function (tx) {

tx.executeSql(selectKasir, [], function (tx, result) {

dataset = result.rows;

for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

item = dataset.item(i);

var linkeditdelete = '' + item['namamenu'] + '';

$("#results").append(linkeditdelete);
}

});

});
}
```

and now i want to add some toggle button and store it to database, some thing like this:

```
<li class="item item-toggle widget uib_w_377 pengaturan-margin" data-uib="ionic/toggle" data-ver="0">Pembelian
 <label class="toggle">
 <input type="checkbox">
 <div class="track">
 <div class="handle"></div>
 </div>
 </label>
 </li>
```

how can i store the toggle to my sqlite database ?